# Runtime Error during iteration?

Tags: python, iteration

One of the distinctions between a list and a set is a list can be altered during iteration -- we can append to it in a loop, etc. However, if we try to add to a set during a for loop, runtime error is raised. However, how does Python detect that set.add() is being used in a loop and then raises the run time error? If I try to recreate my pseudo list class and raise runtime error in my class's append function, do I simply overload __iter__ to prevent any appending?

For an example:

```
a_set = {1,2,3,4}
a_list = [1,2,3,4]

for i in a_list:
     a_list.append(5)
```

Which results in an infinite loop

```
for j in a_set:
    a_set.add(5)
```

Which results in runtime error.

They both have __iter__ functions so in my pseudo list class, how should I overload __iter__ such that it will raise runtime error like a set does?

Comment: A set is a type of list, so I'm confused. Can you provide an working example?

Comment: A set is a type of list? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I guess it depends on how you use "list". I think of "list" as an iterable data type, which a set is. I guess you're thinking of 'list' as how I would put an "array". Anyways you're not wrong here, I was just confused for a minute...

Comment: Try [this](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/loop-better-deeper-look-iteration-python) web page. Sorry I don't have time to dive into this myself right now, but in skimming though the latter half of the article I think you might be able to find an answer.

Comment: @Spencer a "list" is usually referring to [an abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), or a  concrete implementation, which may use a linked-list data structure or dynamic array or whatever. Suffice it to say, in Python, this always refers to a `list`, which is the name of the type. Python does have arrays, but they are rarely used (`import array`), unless you are talking about `numpy` arrays. A set is another built-in data type, the `set` type, which implements the [set abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: @Spencer for what it's worth, a CPython `list` is implemented with a dynamic array, and `set` is implemented with a hash-set.

Answer (score 3):

When entering a for loop, Python first calls `iter` on the *iterable* to get or create an *iterator*. Then the loop asks for the `next` item from the iterator until a `StopIteration` exception is seen (unless flow has exited the loop earlier by a `break`, a `return` statement, or some other exception).  A for-loop such as:

```
for element in iterable:
    ...
```

Could be rewritten approximately like this:

```
it = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        element = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    ...
```

Now, by using a list instance as your *iterable*, you are iterating a different *iterator* type than you are when using a set instance as your *iterable*:

```
>>> iter([0])
<list_iterator at 0xcafef00d>
>>> iter({0})
<set_iterator at 0xdeadbeef>
```

The `set_iterator` type and the `list_iterator` type implement `__next__` differently. Here is the [`setiter_iternext`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/491bbedc209fea314a04cb3015da68fb0aa63238/Objects/setobject.c#L894) function in CPython where the [changing size is guarded against](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/491bbedc209fea314a04cb3015da68fb0aa63238/Objects/setobject.c#L907).  The [`listiter_next`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/491bbedc209fea314a04cb3015da68fb0aa63238/Objects/listobject.c#L3070-L3092) has no such guard.

I hope now you can see how to create a similar safeguard directly in a Python iterator. When you define the `__next__` method, you can check if the size has changed and raise:

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj  # note: you may prefer to use a weakref here
        self.it = iter(obj)
        self.initial_size = len(obj)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if len(self.obj) != self.initial_size:
            raise RuntimeError('changed size...doh!')
        return next(self.it)

class GrumpyList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIterator(self.data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in g:
...     print(i)
...     if i == 2:
...         g.data.append(99)
...         
0
1
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
...
RuntimeError: changed size...doh!
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think the OP's main question was how he could implement a guard like the `set` iterator has, in a custom class. _". . . how should I overload __iter__ such that it will raise runtime error like a set does?"_

Comment: Yes, OK, I will add a minimal example of that.

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Answer (score 2):

It is all in the iterator your iterable class returns. Note, for a set, it's actually the `__next__` method which raises the error, and not necessarily in a for-loop, although a for-loop implicitly calls `__iter__` on an iterable, then calls `__next__` on the resulting iterator and assigns it to the loop variable, and continues to do so at the beginning of each iteration until a `StopIteration` is raised (this is the *iterator protocol*). So, note:

```
In [2]: s = {1,2,3}

In [3]: it = iter(s)

In [4]: next(it)
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: s.add(1)

In [6]: next(it)
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: s.add(99)

In [8]: next(it)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-2cdb14c0d4d6> in <module>()
----> 1 next(it)

RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

As the error implies, it's when the set *changes size* that the error is called. We can implement this doing something like the following:

```
In [11]: class MyListIterator:
    ...:     def __init__(self, origin):
    ...:         self.origin = origin
    ...:         self.original_size = len(origin)
    ...:         self.i = 0
    ...:     def __iter__(self):
    ...:         return self
    ...:     def __next__(self):
    ...:         if len(self.origin) != self.original_size:
    ...:             raise RuntimeError("MyList changed size during iteration!")
    ...:         elif self.i == self.original_size:
    ...:             raise StopIteration
    ...:         x = self.origin.data[self.i]
    ...:         self.i += 1
    ...:         return x
    ...:
    ...: class MyList:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.data = [1,2,3]
    ...:     def __iter__(self):
    ...:         return MyListIterator(self)
    ...:     def __len__(self):
    ...:         return len(self.data)
    ...:     def append(self, item):
    ...:         self.data.append(item)
    ...:
```

And now:

```
In [12]: mylist = MyList()

In [13]: for x in mylist:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
1
2
3

In [14]: for x in mylist:
    ...:     mylist.append(3)
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3bd26e0c08b9> in <module>()
----> 1 for x in mylist:
      2     mylist.append(3)
      3     print(x)
      4

<ipython-input-14-f69ab7d03470> in __next__(self)
      8     def __next__(self):
      9         if len(self.origin) != self.original_size:
---> 10             raise RuntimeError("MyList changed size during iteration!")
     11         elif self.i == self.original_size:
     12             raise StopIteration

RuntimeError: MyList changed size during iteration!
```

Note, you can see the `1` was printed before the error was raised, that's because it isn't until `__next__` is called implicitly by the for-loop right before the second iteration (or at the beginning of the second iteration, however you want to think about it), that the error is raised.

Comment: In a perfect world, the OP wouldn't need such a guard. Nobody should have any business modifying an iterable while iterating over it in the first place.

Comment: Very detailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = {1,2,3,4,656,6,34,23,24,4,23,52}
>>> x
{1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 6, 656, 52, 23, 24}
>>> for i in x:
...     x.add('what')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
>>>
```

As you can see from the first 3 lines, sets do not store any index meaning they are not ordered. Since it is unordered it can't be sure what the next item will be if you add a new one during iteration; hence the runtime error.

```
>>> class C:
...     someiter = 1,2,3,4,5
...     def __iter__(s):
...         return iter(s.someiter)
...
>>> for i in C():
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
>>>
```

You mentioned it yourself, python calls theobject.__iter__ when you put it in a for loop; which means you are not simply adding something to your set, you are calling iter first, this is how python knows the difference.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But how does Python detect that we are trying to add to a set in a loop versus adding to a set outside of a loop? Because one raises runtime error but the other does not.

Comment: @Tyler So I think what your question should be is "How can I detect if python is currently in an iteration loop?" Not that I can answer that... but it might help to clarify your question above a bit more.

Comment: lol thank you for the downvote, would love to hear the reason tho.

Comment: Are you suggesting in your edit that \__iter__ is called in set but not in list when using a for loop and that's how Python knows the difference?

Comment: Again. You are calling \_\_iter\_\_ in both. Sets however are unordered. Which means that when you add or remove, the order can change. Which again means that python doesn't know what will be the next item. Hence the error. On lists however when you insert or append, the next item is always known. You are either appending to the list which means it becomes the last item, or you are inserting to the list which means that you are literally giving the index and python still knows where it is and acts accordingly.

Comment: Could it be that you're confused about what I'm asking? I'm not asking about _why_ it works, I'm asking about _how_. I understand that lists have order and sets do not. Anywho, the other answer already provided me the documentation.